# Private inner module returning private item gives "private type in public interface" error

Tags: module, interface, rust, private, public

In the below example, the module `outer` has a private type `Private` and a private inner module `inner`. `inner` is able to access `Private` (because **child modules can access their parent's private items**, even if they are not parked as public).

`inner` defines a function `not_really_public_interface()`. While it is marked as public, **it is really only available to `outer`** because `inner` itself is not public.

*outer.rs*

```
struct Private;
mod inner {
  use super::Private;
  pub fn not_really_public_interface() -> Private {
    Private
  }
}
```

This compiles without any problems.

`outer` should be able to use `inner::not_really_public_interface()` to obtain `Private`, as long as it makes sure not to export it. So let's do that:

```
pub fn main() {
  let _ = self::inner::not_really_public_interface();
}
```

Right?

*stderr*

```
error[E0446]: private type `Private` in public interface
 --> src/outer.rs:4:3
  |
4 | /   pub fn not_really_public_interface() -> Private {
5 | |     Private
6 | |   }
  | |___^ can't leak private type
```

**Wat.** This is counter-intuitive to me for several reasons:

- The former code produces no error even though it defines a function with an interface Rust considers to "leak". The error only occurs when the `outer` attempt to *use* this function.
- The only place `inner` could possibly "leak" `Private` is to *the module that defined it*.

So my questions are:

- What exactly is going on here that causes Rust to conclude that any part of this interface leaks? It seems like it treats `Private` as if it were defined in `inner`.
- Is there a context in which this makes perfect sense? My first thought was that this was a bug in the compiler or oversight in the privacy design, but I doubt that's the case.
- Is there a way to work around this without creating another module? I believe I can create a wrapper module and then just make `Private` public within `outer` and `inner`, but I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: When I try to compile the code you've suggested even without using `not_really_public_interface` I get the same error. Here's the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=179af72b7f3579e387328978c6a76075).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function `not_really_public_interface` *is* public so it could be used by *any* other module. But the `Private` struct can only be accessed by your root and `inner` modules.

The leak would occur if another module imported `not_really_public_interface`. Rust is complaining that this *could* happen because it reports errors locally, rather than taking a "whole world" view across all usages in all modules and crates. Ultimately, this approach is more predictable for humans to reason about and faster for the machine.

Rust lets you control the visibility more precisely though. If you tell it that the function is *only* available to the module one level up (the `super` module) then it knows there is no possibility of a leak:

```
mod inner {
    use super::Private;

    pub(super) fn not_really_public_interface() -> Private { Private }
}
```

You could also use `crate` instead of `super`, to mean any module in the same crate. Or, if the super module had a name, e.g. `my_mod`, you could use `pub(in ::my_mod)` to target it specifically.

Comment: Another module cannot import `not_really_public_interface` unless it also sees `inner` and thus `Private` I think the problem only arises when some module *reexports* `not_really_public_interface` either directly or with a glob `pub use inner::*;` but it would be allowed to do so and that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution in my case was replacing `pub` with `pub(crate)`

Comment: `pub(crate)` is a (worse) alternative to `pub(super)` here.