# What's the best way to use a private type in a public function?

Tags: rust, private, public

I have the following code:

```rust
use std::convert::{From, Into};

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
enum FindBy<'f> {
    U(&'f usize),
    S(&'f str),
    ST(&'f String),
}

impl<'f> From<&'f usize> for FindBy<'f> {
    fn from(v: &'f usize) -> Self {
        Self::U(v)
    }
}

impl<'f> From<&'f str> for FindBy<'f> {
    fn from(v: &'f str) -> Self {
        Self::S(v)
    }
}

impl TileSet {
    pub fn find<'r, 'ts: 'r, K: Into<FindBy<'r>>>(&'ts self, key: K) -> &'r Tile {
        match key.into() {
            FindBy::S(k) => &self.list.get(k).unwrap(),
            FindBy::ST(k) => &self.list.get(k).unwrap(),
            FindBy::U(k) => match &self.list.get_index(*k) {
                Some((_, v)) => &v,
                _ => todo!(),
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Results in this warning:

```
warning: private type `prelude::sys::element::tile_set::FindBy<'r>` in public interface (error E0446)
  --> src/sys/element/tile_set.rs:46:5
   |
46 | /     pub fn find<'r, 'ts: 'r, K: Into<FindBy<'r>>>(&'ts self, key: K) -> &'r Tile {
47 | |         match key.into() {
48 | |             FindBy::S(k) => &self.list.get(k).unwrap(),
49 | |             FindBy::ST(k) => &self.list.get(k).unwrap(),
...  |
54 | |         }
55 | |     }
   | |_____^
   |
   = warning: this was previously accepted by the compiler but is being phased out; it will become a hard error in a future release!
   = note: for more information, see issue #34537 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34537>
```

`FindBy` is never exposed — it's purpose is to provide a whitelist to allow for one argument to take multiple types, but the type itself is never intended to be used outside, internal use only, yet it's complaining of a private type in a public interface.

Allow me to clarify, `FindBy` is never, ever going to be used outside of the module/file it's inside of, however it's as part of the function signature and the function is `public`.

I don't want to expose `FindBy` and it never is, but because it's used in a public function to provide type whitelisting for the argument, Rust complains.

What's the best way to resolve this?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. The code you have provided does not generate the error you are asking about. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to reference private types from public functions in private modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39334430/155423) or [Private inner module returning private item gives “private type in public interface” error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50753923/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Those questions seem to be about returning private types which is not what I'm asking about as I'm not returning the private type; as I said "but the type itself is never intended to be used outside, internal use only".

Comment: "returning" vs "accepting" is not relevant here, the point is that the types are in the signature. Did you **attempt** the solutions to see if they work?

Comment: [The code you have provided does not generate the error you are asking about](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=01f605c2aba371a533cd0dcff96b80d8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual solution to restricting a parameter to one of a few possible types is to use [Sealed traits](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/future-proofing.html#sealed-traits-protect-against-downstream-implementations-c-sealed).

So, for your `find` function, instead of having an `enum FindBy` and dispatching on its variant, you could have a trait `FindBy` (that's sealed as explained in the link, so nobody else can implement it) that encapsulates the different logic for each of the types, roughly like this (not tested):

```rust
impl TileSet {
    pub fn find<K: FindBy>(&self, key: K) -> &Tile {
        key.find_in(self)
    }
}

pub trait FindBy: private::Sealed {
    fn find_in<'ts>(self, _: &'ts TileSet) -> &'ts Tile;
}

impl FindBy for &'_ usize {
    fn find_in(self, tileset: &'ts TileSet) -> &'ts Tile {
        match &tileset.list.get_index(*self) {
            Some((_, v)) => &v,
            _ => todo!(),
        }
    }
}

// impl FindBy for &'_ str { ... }
// impl FindBy for &'_ String { ... }

mod private {
    pub trait Sealed {}

    impl Sealed for &'_ usize {}
    impl Sealed for &'_ str {}
    impl Sealed for &'_ String {}
}
```

You could also move the method (that I called `find_in`) to the private trait if you want it to only be usable through `TileSet::find`. Also, you might want to consider implementing the trait for `usize` rather than `&'_ usize` (but maybe you have a good reason for it to be a reference).

Comment: Then you agree that this question is a duplicate of [How to reference private types from public functions in private modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39334508/155423)?

Comment: So, make the type public and change `impl TileSet` to be `impl TileSet: private::Sealed`?

Comment: Shepmaster: I think this question is different enough to have its own answer, because really the private enum in the OP only exists to allow `find` to take multiple different public types as its argument. Your answer on that question doesn't mention sealed traits because they're most likely not applicable there; here they are though IMHO.

Comment: Thermatix: No, but I'll add to my answer to clarify.

Comment: @jplatte, thank you for being the only individual reasonable enough to actually read the question.